# How to select 1 last news for each category with join clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I Have two tables. I want to show one last news in each related category on index page. Therefore I want to ask "How can I select 1 last news for each category with join clause in mysql?"
:

**category_table:**

```
id|category_name|
--+-------------+
1 | Sport       |
2 | Policy      |
3 | Hot News    |
```

**all_news_table:**

```
id | category_id | title
---+-------------+---------------
1  |3            | addsad
2  |2            | asdad
3  |1            | sdadasdasd
3  |2            | sdadasdasd
4  |1            | dsasdas
5  |3            | asdasdasd
6  |3            | sdasdas
```

Comment: what do u mean by last news here???

Comment: Last news that is: last news id according to related category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that higher id's denote 'newer' news items.

First select the highest id per news category in a subselect, then select all the data for those news items.

```
SELECT c.category_name, a.title, a.body
FROM all_news_table a
INNER JOIN category_table c ON (a.category_id = c.id)
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT max(a1.id) FROM all_news_table a1
    GROUP BY a1.category_id)
```

Comment: @Johan, is there any other solution? Because it takes too much time (**Query took 25.9456 sec**)

Comment: @EmilAzizov, add indexes to a.cat_id, c.id and a.id. The id's should be primary keys.

Comment: @Johan, sorry how can I do that? I use phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Johan: possibly adding also an index on (a.category_id ASC, a.id ASC) could help if the table is really big

Comment: @Emil Azizov: If you find an answer **great**, you should accept it by clicking on the tick mark below the answer score. That's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: If you mean inside query, exactly where do I have to add (a.category_id ASC, a.id ASC)

Comment: @EmilAzizov, you don't add indexes to a query, you add then to a table `ALTER TABLE category_table ADD PRIMARY INDEX (id)`, `ALTER TABLE all_news_table ADD INDEX (category_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
SELECT c.category_name, a.title, a.body
  FROM all_news_table a
 INNER JOIN category_table c ON c.id = a.category_id
  LEFT JOIN all_news_table a2 ON a2.category_id = a.category_id
                             AND a2.id > a.id
 WHERE a2.id IS NULL
```

As for Johan's answer, this might require indexes on `category_id` and `id` and assumes you have a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `id` column of table `all_news_table`.